# Is there a way to simplify this function (a series)?

Tags: sequences-and-series

There's this function that I'm curious to simplify.
$$
f(x,m,n)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{k}{k+m}\times\frac{x^{k-n}}{(k-n)!}, \quad n,m\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
The only thing that came to me was that if we multiply and divide by $k-n$, it "kind of" looks like it has elements of $e^x$ with a coefficient. But that coefficient has $k$ in it so I'm not sure what to do with it.

I would be thankful to receive some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $k-n=j$, the series becomes
$$
f(x,m,n)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{j+n}{j+m+n}\frac{x^j}{j!}
$$
I'll assume $m>0$ and $n>0$. Consider
$$
g(x,m,n)=x^{m+n}f(x,m,n)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{j+n}{j+n+m}\frac{x^{j+m+n}}{j!}
$$
If we differentiate term by term, we get (primes denote derivatives with respect to $x$)
$$
g'(x,m,n)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+n)\frac{x^{j+m+n-1}}{j!}=x^{m}\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+n)\frac{x^{j+n-1}}{j!}
$$
If we set
$$
h(x,n)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+n)\frac{x^{j+n-1}}{j!}
$$
we see that $h(x,n)=H'(x,n)$, where
$$
H(x,n)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^{j+n}}{j!}=x^ne^x
$$
Therefore
$$
h(x,n)=(nx^{n-1}+x^n)e^x
$$
and so
$$
g'(x,m,n)=(nx^{m+n-1}+x^{m+n})e^x
$$
Now you can integrate and recall that
$$
f(x,m,n)=\frac{1}{x^{m+n}}g(x,m,n)
$$

Comment: I'm new to this platform so could anyone please explain what -1 next to the answer means?

Comment: In this case it means that somebody deemed I should not have answered. I don’t care much, but I’m pretty sure to know who’s that user.

Comment: This approach is just brilliant. In the original problem we have $a(x-b)$ instead of just $x$. I tried to follow the same path and if I'm not mistaken, the equivalent of $g'$ from above is $g'\left(x, m, n\right) = a\left(a(x-b)\right)^{m+n-1} \left(n+a(x- b)\right)e^{a(x-b)}$ but I cannot find $f$. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @Sigma Just set $y=a(x-b)$ and do the same; just back substitute at the end.